# I am having two errors in my applications, 1 too many vulnerabilities, 2 and i can't push to heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I am facing some problem with my React Application. I am working on Mernstack, and my front-end is refusing to push to Heroku, I have tried every example that I saw on StackOverflow but none were able to resolve the problem.

1 error: Heroku is rejecting the application, this is what I see when I try to push to Heroku.

```
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: !   Push rejected to salty-thicket-72247.
To https://git.heroku.com/salty-thicket-72247.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/salty-thicket-72247.git'
```

and so many vulnerable packages, this is what I see when I do npm install

```
found 1 high severity vulnerability
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

[image: Npm vulnerabilities]

[image: Heroku issues]

Comment: So you did `npm audit`, right?

Comment: Yes, I did npm audit but it didn't solve the problem @tadman

Comment: Please post text, not images of text. What did `npm audit` tell you?

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: `npm audit` doesn't fix the problem, it explains more about what the problem is. If you read more careully you can see there's `npm audit fix` as well. NPM is trying to help you out here.

Answer (score -1):

your push fails because there is some precommit hook installed.
It looks like that hook tests, if your commit compiles, but it does not.

Comment: I don't think i fully understood what you meant, do you mind explaining it better for me to understand? @midnight

Comment: I have managed to get it to work. the problem was that the material UI that I installed in a branch did not get added into the master branch when I merged the branch to master, but it exists in Json-lock.